# Why the query is returning only a single record instead of many?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm using PHP and MySql. Following is my code:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","XYZ","pqr") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("LMN", $con);
$sql  =" SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( transaction_date ) , '%d/%m/%Y') 'date', COUNT(*) 'total count', SUM(transaction_status = 'success') ";
        $sql .=" success, SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') inprocess, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') fail, ";
        $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') cancelled FROM user_transaction WHERE ";
        $sql .=" transaction_date >= 1325376000 AND transaction_date <= 1373846400 GROUP BY date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)) ";
$r= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

        $result  = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        print_r($result); 
die;
```

If I run the above query in PHPMyadmin it is giving me the perfect result(i.e. 47 matching records), but when I run through the PHP file it is giving me only the single record s follows:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 11/04/2012
    [total count] => 1
    [success] => 0
    [inprocess] => 0
    [fail] => 0
    [cancelled] => 1
)
```

Actually this one is the first matched record. Can you help me in getting all the matching records array as I got in PHPMyadmin? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` returns the next record in the resultset.  You need to call it repeatedly, until no further records remain.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array()` is usually called in a `while` loop because it returns `false` when there are no more records to read.

To fetch all records into an array:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $rows[] = $row;
```

but this is generally very inefficient and wastes a lot of memory. Put your actual processing in the loop if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to get several results you should iterate it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo($row[0]);  //example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
While($result = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
   print_r($result);
}
```

Read more about **mysql_fetch_array** function, it return results one by one, thefor you need to use While :)